# c makefile - no input file

Tags: c, makefile

So here my code for a makefile :

```
    CC=gcc 
    CFLAGS= -g -W -Wall -o
    EXEC=program
    all :   $(EXEC)
    program:    apple.o cream.o cake.o  program.o
                $(CC)   $(CFLAGS)   program apple.o cream.o cake.o  program.0

    program.o:  program.c   apple.o cream.o cake.o
                $(CC)   $(CFLAGS)   program.c

    apple.o:    apple.c apple.h
                $(CC)   $(CFLAGS)   apple.c apple.h

    cream.o:    apple.o cream.c cream.h
                $(CC)   $(CFLAGS)   cream.c cream.h

    cake.o:     cake.c  cake.h  cream.o apple.o
                $(CC)   $(CFLAGS)   cake.c  cake.h
clean:
    -rm -rf *.o $(EXEC)
```

And im stuck with an error :
***gcc: no input file
make: ***[program.o] Error 1***

Just to let you know.

- apple.c has -> #include "apple.h"
- cream.c has  -> #include "cream.h" and  #include "apple.h"
- cake.c has  -> #include "cake.h",   #include "apple.h" & #include "cream.h"
- program.c has -> #include "cake.h",   #include "apple.h" & #include "cream.h"

I want to be able to create a makefile that will produce my exec 'program'. And i've read that i can use de -I flag which will look into the directory for the include header. But when i add the -I in my CFLAGS, it's getting worst

Thank you very much.

Comment: you have `program.0` (with a zero char `0` instead of lowercase `o`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CFLAGS= -g -W -Wall -o
:
program.o:  program.c   apple.o cream.o cake.o
    $(CC)   $(CFLAGS)   program.c
```

The problem (one of them) lies there.

Since `CFLAGS` ends with `-o`, the specification for the output file, the command ends up being:

```
gcc -g -W -Wall -o program.c
```

In other words, you're specifying `program.c` as the *output* file and providing no *input* file.

You need to specify the output file with something like:

```
program: program.c apple.o cream.o cake.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) program program.c apple.o cream.o cake.o
```

(though there are probably better ways to do this by using the meta-variables provided by `make`).

You also seem to be under some confusion about the compilation process. Despite the fact your *rule* is for building the object file `program.o`, the compiler options you have will try to generate a final executable (since they do not have `-c`).